# setting float pointer into character array read from header file

Tags: c, arrays, image, pointers, header

First, sorry for the long question, but it should be easy to follow. Say I use a struct image which contains channel, height, width number, and a pointer to the actual image data of `c*h*w` number of float values. I write the image structure array and the image data array (each image's data concatenated) into separate files using fwrite to load them in another system later. The loading system has no file system, so I want to pass the file as a header file and I used `xxd -i bin_file` to make the stored binary file data into character array(shown below) in the header file. In the load program, the image array and data array(concatenated for the images) are just static charater array as declared in the #include header files. I copy the image structures and overwrite the data pointer to point the data element corresponding to each image's data start location. But when I print the loaded data, only some starting data of the first image is correct and all following data are zero. I can't figure out what's wrong. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?
Below is shown the test code I made. (for channel = 2, height = 3, width = 4).

=== image.h ===

```
typedef struct {
    int c;
    int h;
    int w;
    float *data;
} image;
```

=== store.c ===

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "image.h"

float data1_0[24] = \
{0.840188,0.394383,0.783099,0.798440,0.911647,0.197551,0.335223,0.768230,0.277775,0.553970,0.477397,0.628871,0.364784,0.513401,0.952230,0.916195,0.635712,0.717297,0.141603,0.606969,0.016301,0.242887,0.137232,0.804177};

float data1_1[24] = \
{0.156679,0.400944,0.129790,0.108809,0.998925,0.218257,0.512932,0.839112,0.612640,0.296032,0.637552,0.524287,0.493583,0.972775,0.292517,0.771358,0.526745,0.769914,0.400229,0.891529,0.283315,0.352458,0.807725,0.919026};

image alpha_images[2];

main()
{

int i;
image ab;

alpha_images[0].c = 2;
alpha_images[0].h = 3;
alpha_images[0].w = 4;
alpha_images[0].data = data1_0;

alpha_images[1].c = 2;
alpha_images[1].h = 3;
alpha_images[1].w = 4;
alpha_images[1].data = data1_1;

FILE *fpi = fopen("alpha_image.bin","wb");
FILE *fpd = fopen("alpha_data.bin","wb");

for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    ab = alpha_images[i];
    if (fwrite(&ab, sizeof(image), 1, fpi) != 1) printf ("error! 1234 \n");
    if (fwrite(ab.data, ab.h*ab.w*ab.c, 1, fpd) != 1) printf ("error! 5678 \n");
}

printf("size of image = %d\n", sizeof(image));
}
```

I do `xxd -i alpha_image.bin` to make alpha_image_bin.h shown below in hex.

=== alpha_image_bin.h ===

```
unsigned char alpha_image_bin[] = {
  0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x0b, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x0b, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
unsigned int alpha_image_bin_len = 48;
```

.
and `xxd -i alpha_data.bin` to make alpha_data_bin.h shown below in hex.

=== alpha_data_bin.h ===

```
nsigned char alpha_data_bin[] = {
  0x90, 0x16, 0x57, 0x3f, 0x92, 0xec, 0xc9, 0x3e, 0x2d, 0x79, 0x48, 0x3f,
  0x90, 0x66, 0x4c, 0x3f, 0xb3, 0x61, 0x69, 0x3f, 0xcf, 0x4a, 0x4a, 0x3e,
  0x76, 0x70, 0x20, 0x3e, 0x88, 0x48, 0xcd, 0x3e, 0xab, 0xe7, 0x04, 0x3e,
  0x41, 0xd7, 0xde, 0x3d, 0x8c, 0xb9, 0x7f, 0x3f, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x5f, 0x3e
};
unsigned int alpha_data_bin_len = 48;
```

I checked the generated values are correct when expressed in ieee754 single precision float (little endian).
The converted header files are as follows.
=== alpha_image_bin.h ===

```
unsigned char alpha_image_bin[] = {
  0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x0a, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

unsigned int alpha_image_bin_len = 48;

=== alpha_data_bin.h ===

```
unsigned char alpha_data_bin[] = {
  0x90, 0x16, 0x57, 0x3f, 0x92, 0xec, 0xc9, 0x3e, 0x2d, 0x79, 0x48, 0x3f,
  0x90, 0x66, 0x4c, 0x3f, 0xb3, 0x61, 0x69, 0x3f, 0xcf, 0x4a, 0x4a, 0x3e,
  0x76, 0x70, 0x20, 0x3e, 0x88, 0x48, 0xcd, 0x3e, 0xab, 0xe7, 0x04, 0x3e,
  0x41, 0xd7, 0xde, 0x3d, 0x8c, 0xb9, 0x7f, 0x3f, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x5f, 0x3e
};
unsigned int alpha_data_bin_len = 48;
```

Below is the loading program.

=== load.c ===

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "image.h"

#include "alpha_image_bin.h"
#include "alpha_data_bin.h"

image alpha_image[2];

main()
{

int i, j;

image *iptr = (image *)&alpha_image_bin[0];
int dptr = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    alpha_image[i] = *iptr; // copy c,h,w
    alpha_image[i].data = (float *)&alpha_data_bin[dptr]; // overwrite data pointer
    iptr++; dptr+= 2*3*4*sizeof(float);
}

// check loading
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    printf("c = %d, h = %d, w = %d\n", alpha_image[i].c, alpha_image[i].h, alpha_image[i].w);
    for(j=0; j<2*3*4; j++) {
        printf("%f ", alpha_image[i].data[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

When I run load, it gives me this result

=== load result ===

```
c = 2, h = 3, w = 4
0.840188 0.394383 0.783099 0.798440 0.911647 0.197551 0.156679 0.400944 0.129790 0.108809 0.998925 0.218257 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
c = 2, h = 3, w = 4
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

The correct data should be as shown in store.c.

=== expected correct result ===

```
float data1_0[24] = \
{0.840188,0.394383,0.783099,0.798440,0.911647,0.197551,0.335223,0.768230,0.277775,0.553970,0.477397,0.628871,0.364784,0.513401,0.952230,0.916195,0.635712,0.717297,0.141603,0.606969,0.016301,0.242887,0.137232,0.804177};

float data1_1[24] = \
{0.156679,0.400944,0.129790,0.108809,0.998925,0.218257,0.512932,0.839112,0.612640,0.296032,0.637552,0.524287,0.493583,0.972775,0.292517,0.771358,0.526745,0.769914,0.400229,0.891529,0.283315,0.352458,0.807725,0.919026};
```

What is wrong with the load.c code? (note sizeof(image) is 24 because there are 4 bytes padding before the data pointer).

Comment: `image *iptr = (image *) &alpha_image_bin[0];` lacks code to allow this to compile.  Post needed code to allow compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you described is not in `load.c`. It is in `store.c`:

```
    if (fwrite(ab.data, ab.h*ab.w*ab.c, 1, fpd) != 1) printf ("error! 5678 \n");
```

This only writes the first `24` bytes of `ab.data` instead of writing all `24 * sizeof (float)` bytes (assuming `float` is 4 bytes, you only wrote the first 6 floats of each image).

Fix it by changing to:

```
    if (fwrite(ab.data, sizeof(float)*ab.h*ab.w*ab.c, 1, fpd) != 1) printf ("error! 5678 \n");
```

And because of that error the char-array in `alpha_data_bin.h`, that you created from the file, is too short.

Comment: Thanks. That was the error. Actually I originally wanted to use the static array (of image, and of data) as is without copying the struct array. Can you suggest me how I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

In `float data1_0[24] = \` you can remove the backslash. I don't know if it hurts, but it certainly isn't necessary as the C compiler is line-independent (it just continues parsing on the next line).

In `fwrite(&ab, sizeof(image), 1, fpi)` you are also writing the pointer to the data. That is useless as you cannot read it back with meaning. Of couse you can read it back but you must then ignore any value of the pointer and replace it with the pointer to the actual data.

Finally, you forget to close the files, so add two calls to `fclose()`.

---

In load.c I don't see you opening any files, so how do you expect to load anything??? Ah...you save it as .bin and then include it in a .h. Sounds a bit stupid: with every change you have to recompile it. If I were a teacher you got a fail for this setup. Just use malloc to allocate the memory then read the binary data into it.

Comment: " `ab` is not initialized" Yes it is: `ab = alpha_images[i];`

Comment: Thanks, @SiggiSv; didn't see that.

Comment: The loading system doesn't have malloc (no OS, just bare metal).

Comment: @Paul Oglivie, actually I originally wanted to use the static array (of image, and of data) as is without copying the struct array. Can you suggest me how I can do it?